# Pass Data On Page NavigationService.GoBack()

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I created a navigation event where Page1 TextBox1.Text Transfers To Page2 TextBox2.Text

My Page1 Code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        string uri = "/Page1.xaml?Text=";
        uri += TextBox1.Text;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

My Page2 Code:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        IDictionary<string, string> parameters = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;
        if (parameters.ContainsKey("Text"))
        {
            TextBox2.Text = parameters["Text"];
        }
    }
```

Above code works fine when Navigating from Page1 to Page2 but it give error while trying to use

```
    NavigationService.GoBack();  method
```

when i am passing the text from page2 to page1 i dont want to create another instance of page1 I just want to go back to old instance but while doing that my text is not transferring PLEASE HELP...

Comment: One way to do that is to store the variables in a shared context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671117/how-to-store-and-use-application-wide-object-windows-phone-7-8/18671269#18671269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Link hope so it will help you

[Pass Values Between Pages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/724883/How-to-Pass-Values-Between-Pages-in-Windows-Phone)

On page2 the data is saved using

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Text"] = txtboxvalue.Text;
```

and can be get at page1 using

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("Text"))
                txtvalue.Text = (string)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Text"];


        }
```